# java sorting for some special chars,numbers, alphabets and blanks together

Tags: java, sorting

I need to sort the symbols mentioned in the map in the following order.

First blanks , second * , third ** , 4th lower case letters in alphabetic order , 5th uppercase letters in alphabetic order  , 6th Numbers in Ascending order and last ()symbol

```
  Map<String, String> symbols = new HashMap<String, String>();
  symbols.put("001","*");
  symbols.put("002","**");
  symbols.put("003"," ");
  symbols.put("004","s");
  symbols.put("005","A");
  symbols.put("006","g");
  symbols.put("007","f");
  symbols.put("008","6");
  symbols.put("009","9");
  symbols.put("0010","()");
  symbols.put("0011","*");
  symbols.put("0012","10");
  symbols.put("0013","Y");
  symbols.put("0014","**");
  symbols.put("0015","()");
  symbols.put("0016","**");
  symbols.put("0017"," ");
```

For clarity: Final solution would be LinkedHashMap with sorted records as i mentioned.

Comment: What is your question? Where is your try?

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you

```
    ` Map<Integer, String> symbols = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
      symbols.put(1,"*");
      symbols.put(2,"**");
      .............`
```

Comment: No.should not change map's key. that is needed.

Comment: Sorry for that,with key as integer thought it be easy to sort

Comment: I need sorting based on the  value of the map.

Comment: are values in map static or dynamic